# PreferenceActivity with multiple PreferenceScreens without Headers

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, preferencescreen, preferencefragment

I would like to do a normal PreferenceActivity (in the old style, without headers), but with fragments and without using `addPreferencesFromResource(id)` (because deprecation).
Right now I achieved this by putting this in my `onCreate`:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new PreferencesFragment()).commit();
```

And my `PreferencesFragment` looks something like this:

```
public static class PreferencesFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

Obviously I also implemented the `isValidFragment` method:

```
@Override
protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
    return PreferencesFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || InnerFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
}
```

And it's working just fine. However, there is a problem when having `PreferenceScreen`'s inside my `preferences.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--  ...  -->
    <PreferenceScreen android:fragment="net.chaozspike.batterynotifier.SettingsActivity$InnerFragment"
        android:summary="@string/settings_activity_prefs_display_night_mode_sum"
        android:title="@string/settings_activity_prefs_display_night_mode" />
    <!--  ...  -->
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I have the following problem: the new preference screen shows on top of the normal one, and I know it's probably because I replaced the default `R.id.content`. Screenshot:

[image: screenshot not loding]

However I want to fix this problem without using deprecated stuff or headers. Is that possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the solution by myself. If I am not going to make a fragment-based, header-based SettingsActivity, but still want to not use deprecated methods, then I have to not use fragments at all except for the one that is used to replace the main view. In other words, I had to remove the `InnerFragment` and so I could also remove the `isValidFragment` method. And I moved all the code in the other XML file to the first one like this:

**First file (old):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--  ...  -->
    <PreferenceScreen android:fragment="net.chaozspike.batterynotifier.SettingsActivity$InnerFragment"
        android:summary="@string/settings_activity_prefs_display_night_mode_sum"
        android:title="@string/settings_activity_prefs_display_night_mode" />
    <!--  ...  -->
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**First file (new):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--  ...  -->
    <PreferenceScreen android:summary="@string/settings_activity_prefs_display_night_mode_sum"
        android:title="@string/settings_activity_prefs_display_night_mode" >
        <!-- Contents of second file here>
        <CheckBoxPreference /> etc.
    </PreferenceScreen>
    <!--  ...  -->
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply use `PreferenceActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT` and `PreferenceActivity.EXTRA_NO_HEADERS` to show only one fragment and skip the headers:

```
//Note #1: ExtendedPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity 
//Note #2: ExtendedPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment and is 
//declared as an inner static class in ExtendedPreferenceActivity
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExtendedPreferenceActivity.class );
intent.putExtra(PreferenceActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT, ExtendedPreferenceActivity.ExtendedPreferenceFragment.class.getName() );
intent.putExtra(PreferenceActivity.EXTRA_NO_HEADERS, true );
startActivity(intent);
```